# On using polymorphism to display iPhone/iPad ViewControllers

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

When developing a universal binary for both iPhone and iPad apps, I noticed that many developers use a unique ViewController and add the

> if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

to separate their logic. I've also seen this many times in Apple's iOS documentation.

However, I'm really not a big fan of this approach, since it clutters the code and makes it harder to maintain, especially when the iPad and iPhone logic are quite different.

So I was thinking of using an abstract ViewController class and instantiating a specific ViewController for iPhone or iPad (depending of the platform) every time. I would then have a single "if" at every ViewController transition, and I could use polymorphism to make the code cleaner.

Is this the recommended way of doing things? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Both ways will work. It's partly about personal preference and partly about how different the 2 platform implementations will be. If they are similar then you should find that there are very few places where you need conditional code. Likewise, if they are different and you choose to use different classes then likely the only conditional code will be to load the root view controller. After that each class will be platform specific (or have a platform specific subclass) so special logic and handling pushing / presenting view controllers would usually be handled there.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you use two different storyboards then there is no need for an "if" at all. You have a main storyboard that loads if this is an iPad and a different main storyboard that loads if this is an iPhone (you set that up in the info.plist file). Now you can actually have completely different sets of view controller if you so desire (and if the interfaces are quite different, that might not be a bad idea).

I have used subclassing in this situation but I always find it terribly confusing. That can be a problem with subclassing! There are better ways to express the common code (i.e. do it in a different class, not the view controller).